# Laravel Vite -- npm run build in one go

Tags: laravel, vite

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/**/*.js',
                'resources/css/**/*.css',                
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

This is my vite.config.js. I can't read all the javascript and css files when using this. It this not possible?

the error is this when running npm run build:

> Could not resolve entry module "resources/css/*". error during build:
> RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "resources/css/*".
> at error (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/GDJES_Online_Portal/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2287:30)
> at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/GDJES_Online_Portal/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24881:20)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)

Comment: Can you share your folder structure for `resources`? Also why not use one js and one css like `aap.js` and `app.css` just have the imports and starting point there, this way all you would need would be something like this `resources/js/app.js` and `resources/css/app.css`